# Steps to create binary for publishing application on Airwatch instead of iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, mdm, airwatch

I want to upload the ipa on Airwatch.Please provide me the steps how to create the build through xcode for uploading it on Airwatch.
I had done some search work and found 
http://www.aerion.fi/blogi/69-simplied-ios-and-android-enrollment

Comment: Do you have an enterprise developer program membership?

Comment: @Paulw11 No i dont have.And i dont want to use enterprise level program. We want to use the AIRWATCH!

Comment: Have you access to the AirWatch Console? i.e. are you an admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an admin, you can upload internal applications for Android, iOS, Mac OS X, Symbian, Windows 8/RT and Windows Phone. To do so, go to: **Apps & Books > Applications > List View > Internal**.

From there, you can upload your `.ipa`. You have various details or parameters to fill out. I recommend you take a look to the `App Wrapping` which secure your app without having to change the code and add an extra layer of security and data loss prevention.

As your app is for iOS, you need to install a provisioning profile on every device which you want the app on.

The AirWatch Online Help is pretty detailed on every step you have to take. You can access all of that if you are an admin in your organization, if not reach your admin. There is also a guide for `App Wrapping` available in the AirWatch Resources on [my.air-watch](http://my.air-watch.com).

Comment: Thank you for the details answer.So while creating the iPA for airwatch we have to use distribution provisioning profile?

Comment: @Developer Quote from the AirWatch Online Help: "For an internal Apple iOS application to work, every device that runs the application must also have the provisioning profile installed on it."

Comment: @Developer Quote from the AirWatch Online Help: "For internal applications, use files and processes from the Apple iOS Developer Enterprise Program. This program facilitates the development of applications for internal use."